# Error al conectar base de datos a php

Tags: php, base-de-datos, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Al intentar conectar una base de datos de Oracle 11g SQL developer con el siguiente código de php, me sale el error **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrpts\ejemplo.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrpts\ejemplo.php on line 4** cuando lo ejecuto en el XAMPP:

```
<?php

// Conectar al servicio XE (es deicr, la base de datos) en la máquina "localhost"
$conn = oci_connect('PROY', '12345');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM CURSOS');
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "") . "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```

Según he mirado en varias soluciones de internet debería tener [OCI8](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.oci8.php), pero no sé como instalarlo, descargo https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/3.2.1/windows pero no se que hacer a continuación.

Comment: Abre una linea de comandos y ejecuta el comando `pecl` como se indica en la liga que señalas.

Comment: lo otro es correr un docker que ya tenga instalado todo lo necesario como el  OCI8 para Oracle https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/enlinea777/php7.4apacheforsqlserverproducion es la mejor opcion, te dejo el acceso a la imagen que uso yo

Answer (score 0):

En tu Xampp debes descomentar en el archivo **php.ini** las extensiones.

> Asi deben estar:
>
> 1. extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
> 2. extension=oci8_19  ; Use with Oracle Database 19 Instant Client

Dependiendo que tipo de cliente estés usando,o des comenta las dos, para eso quita el **;** que tienen al principio, reinicia tu tu servicio de **Apache** y al entrar en **localhost** deberia aparecer el apartado de OCI_8 y con eso deberia funcionar tu conexión a Oracle. *No instales o remplaces archivos .dll o similares, xampp los trae por defecto, solo que en su mayoria desabilitados*, dime si funciono.